# Javascript - two identical objects failing not equals check

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I'm using the `scrollBehavior(to, from, savedPosition)` function of vue-router.

I have the following output for `to.params`:

`{videoId: "18764"}`

and the following for `from.params`:

`{videoId: "18764"}`

however the following `console.log(to.params !== from.params)`

returns `true`

Why is this?

Comment: Because `({} !== {})`.

Comment: brain fart moment should be using .equals

Comment: Because they aren't the same object.  `{}` will never equal `{}`.

Comment: @RickyBarnett You'll need to implement the `equals` method yourself. Objects do not contain such method.

Comment: technically, it's passing the not equals test :p